# Why does saving args[0] into a string give out a index-out-of-range exception?

Tags: c#, indexoutofrangeexception

I've tried to save `args[0]` into `string lemon`, but whatever I tried it didn't work at all, it instead threw an `IndexOutOfRange` exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
> at NHBloater.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users...\Program.cs:line 12

I tried:

- `catch`ing it
- adding `if (args.Length > 0)`
- searching on Google and Stack Overflow

*Edit: I fixed it but don't know how, and the code that's worrying me is `output += inputArray[i]`*

Here is the code with the first line being line 10 without the attempts to fix it:
c#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string lemon = args[0];
    string input = File.ReadAllText(lemon);
    string[] inputArray = input.Split();
    string output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < Convert.ToInt32(args[2]); j++) 
            output += inputArray[i];
    File.WriteAllText(args[1], output);
}
```

Imported libraries:

- `System`
- `System.IO`
- `System.Text`

Arguments:

```
"h.txt"
"h2.txt"
"5"
```

Comment: Your code actually assumes `args` has no less than three arguments since it goes so far as to access `args[2]`, so you probably want a check for that at the beginning.

Comment: when you don't provide any command-line args, what do you expect `args` to contain?

Comment: `i < input.Length` + `output += inputArray[i];` = boom

Comment: You say you provided the arguments but have you actually debugged your code and looked inside of the args array and seen whats in there?

Comment: @Ralf that's a pretty good idea, I'm stupid that I didn't do that earlier.

Comment: outputs System.String[], i dunno why

Comment: That looks like the output of a call to args.ToString() and not what debugging the code should show you if you look at the args array in the debugger.

Comment: Put a breakpoint (do you know how to do that?) at that line and see.

Comment: Unrelated: `Convert.ToInt32(args[2])` Do not trust user input.

Comment: Are you sure that you have an exception at lemon assignment? I copied your code and I see exception at `string input = File.ReadAllText(lemon);`, because I don't have such file.

Comment: @Ralf, i used Console.WriteLine(args);

Comment: That calls args.ToString that is not helpful. You should look up how debugging actually works. Its an extremely helpful tool to understand anything. And its actually easy todo if you have it done at least once ;)

Comment: @ispiro, i added a break point and found it working, pretty strange

Comment: what does `args` contain when debugging? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The link to the documentation with a quick start on debugging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain, it contains "h.txt","h2.txt","5" which is what I wanted

Comment: [Debug.Assert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.assert?view=net-6.0) can also be really helpful, sometimes to quickly check if your assumptions are actually met.

Comment: Can you comment out the complete for-loops and see if it still throws?

Comment: The exception you posted says it occurred at line 12. Which is line 12? Lukasz's question was never answered.

Comment: @gunr2171 Line 12 is `string lemon = args[0];`, but I fixed it without knowing how

Comment: You fixed it by modifying the code, changing the command line arguments, and/or changing the contents of the file you are reading. We don't know what any of those modifications are. Next time please post a [mre].

Comment: @gunr2171 I apologize for that, that might be the case. The thing that's worrying me is `output += inputArray[i];`

Comment: Why would that be worrying you? You just said that `string lemon = args[0];` - the first line of the program - is the line throwing the exception. _NO OTHER STATEMENTS MATTER_. If the first line of the program throws an exception, then the program will never execute the second line.

Comment: Also, please do not edit your question with an answer. You can answer your own question  using the answer box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `args` [won't be null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#command-line-arguments) (See the green **Tip** box in the link), it might be an Array of length 0.

So `args[0]` doesn't exist because it refers to the first item in the array, which doesn't have any items.

If you are really setting it in "command line arguments" in Visual Studio and are really using debug mode - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54189058/939213). Basically - make sure it's all on "Any CPU".

**EDIT**

Change

```
string[] inputArray = input.Split();
```

to

```
string[] inputArray = input.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: The array has a length of 3.

Comment: I like providing the link to the documentation. The docs are pretty consice on the topic. But pointing out the null problematic while that isn't his problem (he got a IndexOutOfRangeException) is distraction from the things he should read in the docs.

Comment: @Matto58 If you put a breakpoint on line 12 and then hover over `args`, I'm pretty sure it will tell you it's empty. (Though I don't know how you're testing it so I don't know why).

Comment: @Matto58 How _are_ you passing those arguments to Main?

Comment: @ispiro Project > Properties > Debug > Command line arguments which is h.txt h2.txt 5

Comment: @Matto58 And how are you running it, by pressing F5 (or clicking Debug)? Or are you clicking the exe file (which won't work)?

Comment: @Matto58 Also, is Visual Studio in `Debug`?

Comment: @ispiro Using F5 and yes, it's in Debug. There's a file called h.txt inside the Debug folder so that should work, btw, the thing that now errors is actually `output += inputArray[i]` and it'S the same exception

Comment: @Matto58 BTW see my edit - the new (last) paragraph in my answer.

Comment: @ispiro I indeed use Any CPU, pretty weird

Comment: @Matto58 The best thing for you to do now it to see [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/7ab4z9u7Q_I?t=77) I set it to the correct time in the video to show you how to put a breakpoint. Breakpoints can be immensely helpful. After setting a breakpoint and running, Visual Studio will stop at that line and then you can hover over variables to see their values.

Comment: @ispiro I know how to do it - thank you, but the values are correct, but that's no longer the issue.

Comment: @Matto58 So now that the problem is in that other line - put a breakpoint on it and hover over `inputArray` and see if it has values. If it does, hover over them to get their value. Etc.

Comment: @ispiro Thanks to you, I _almost_ solved it! The problem is now in `string[] inputArray = input.Split();`, where it returns {"Hello"}, which are contents of the file h.txt. I want it to output {"H","e","l","l","o"}.

Comment: @Matto58 See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking `input.Length` but you are *accessing* `inputArray[i]`.

Answer (score -3):

How do you start Main function (program)? Do you pass arguments to Main function? If not, lenght of your args array is 0 (you don't have any fields in that array).

Comment: I pass a total of 3 arguments to the Main function

Comment: This is not an answer to the question posted

Comment: @Matto58 you keep saying that you provided arguments to the app, but how? Did you actually open project properties and [set command line arguments in the debug tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6475887/995714)?

Comment: @phuclv I did indeed